# phpexcel cannot pass ~

Tags: php, phpexcel

Somewhere in my program my `phpexcel` looks like this:

```php
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

foreach($arrayRawData as $HwKeyColumn => $arrayHwData){
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($counter)
                    -> setCellValue($Header2 . $HeaderCol , $HwKeyColumn);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($mode);
}

foreach($arrayRawData as $HwKeyColumn => $arrayHwData){

        foreach($arrayHwData as $id => $value){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($counter)
                            -> setCellValue($Header . $HeaderCol2,$value);
        }
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('Report.xlsx');
```

I removed the incrementing of cell. It is working correctly. As I manage to save into my Excel with all data intact and no errors in placement.

My problem is in the most inner loop. The `$value` would for example have a value `PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE˜`. But when it saves in the Excel. It is displayed as `PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE`. The `~` is missing. I need to also grab that for error trapping purpose.

I tried to echo `$value` and surely it echoes `PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE˜`. I also tried getting the original value of `$value` and passed it to a new variable. So it now is a new variable with value of `PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE˜` but still when it saves it becomes `PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE`.

//edit
But when I hardcode it like `$value = 'PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE˜'`; The Excell will display correctly. But if I leave it for the loop to change the value of $value it removes ~

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character? E.g. $value = 'PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE\˜';

Comment: I should edit what I said in the above. 

I tried that. And also I feel the problem isn't there.

because if I hardcode it like $value = 'PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE~';

then feed it to value. The output is PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE~

But when I use the loop it goes back to PHYSICALLY DEFECTIVE only

Comment: What encoding are you using? PHPExcel supports UTF-8.

Comment: I have this in my header

header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Origin of `$arrayRawData`, there's something wrong with encoding.